# Reactjs finding `interface` issue with react component class as `Property 'show' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>`

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, tsx

I believe i have declared the `interface` with correct way and implemented with class. but still getting an error as :

`Property 'show' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}>'.ts(2339)`

any one help me understand further here?

here is my code :

```
interface GlobalForm {
    show:boolean
}

export class Footer extends React.Component<GlobalForm> {

    constructor(props:GlobalForm){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show:false
        }
    }
    
    globalForm = (event:React.MouseEvent):void => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState(() => ({show:!this.state.show}))
    }
```

error:

[image: error-on-typescript]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your class decleration to this:

```
export class Footer extends React.Component<{}, GlobalForm> { ...
```

the state types should be in the second parameter

Answer (score 1):

[React.Component](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#class-components) is a generic type (aka `React.Component<PropType, StateType>`), so you want to provide it with (optional) prop and state type parameters.

```
It should be `React.Component<{}, GlobalForm>` in your case.
```